# Calling aspx.cs method from wcf web method

Tags: .net

I have a aspx page and a wcf web service in the same application.  From inside the web method of wcf, can I call a method in the aspx page?  I am thinking of using event.  The aspx page will pubish an event and the web method will subscribe to that event.  Any other way?

Comment: If the method is public you should be able to call it directly, yes. Just make sure you reference it via namespaces properly.

Comment: They are two different classes.  I did not think you can do that.  But I will try it out.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't tried it, but you should be able to instantiate the class and call the method? Sorry I probably should have thought it through more but I don't see why not. Some time ago I did write some .cs code which called a method in a .aspx.cs file

Comment: I tried that and it seemed to work.  I made the method static so I won't have to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

no, you cannot do that. you cannot get a service to then invoke/do a call on the caller.

Maybe using duplex service will help?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731935.aspx

also, this maybe of interest:

http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/working-with-eventscallbacks-in-wcf-a-simplified-beginner-example/